# Meaning of type inference rule for abstraction in lambda-calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, semantics, typing, type-inference, type-checking

Below is a snippet about simply typed lambda-calculus from [CS152: Programming Languages Lecture 9 | Simply Typed Lambda Calculus](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/2011sp/lec9.pdf), on printed‑page 15, indexed 23.

$$
\frac {\Gamma, x: \tau_1 \vdash e: \tau_2}{\Gamma \vdash \lambda x. e: \tau_1 \rightarrow \tau_2}
$$

I read it as: if from a context $\Gamma$ containing $x$ of type $\tau_1$, follows that an expression $e$ is of type $\tau_2$, then from context $\Gamma$, follows that $\lambda x. e$ is of type $\tau_1 \rightarrow \tau_2$.

How does that differs from this:

$$
\frac {\Gamma \vdash x: \tau_1 \land \Gamma \vdash e: \tau_2}{\Gamma \vdash \lambda x. e : \tau_1 \rightarrow \tau_2}
$$

I understand $x$ is expected to typically appears in $e$ (but need not to), however still not see why the second expression (looking more intuitive to me) is not used instead, and so I suspect I may be not really understanding the notation in the first expression.

Is this the same or is this different? If it is not the same, what's the precise meaning of the former and what's the (different) meaning (if it has one) of the latter? Is the former just a way to underline $x$ may be contained in $e$ (i.e., more matter of style than formal meaning)?

Comment: Instead of "context $\Gamma$ containing $x$ of type $\tau_1$" you should say "context $\Gamma$ extended with $x$ of type $\tau_1$". It is assumed here that $\Gamma$ itself does not contain $x$. Thus, below the line, where the context is $\Gamma$, the variable $x$ is "not known".

Comment: A related question and answer on StackOverflow: [“What part of Milner-Hindley do you not understand?”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532552/what-part-of-milner-hindley-do-you-not-understand). Comes with in‑deep explanations on the notations meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that whatever the context $\Gamma$ may imply about the
variable $x$ is irrelevant. This rule is intended to type a
$\lambda$-abstraction, and the variable $x$ may be changed to another
variable by $\alpha$-conversion, without changing the semantics of the
$\lambda$-abstraction,  and thus without changing its type.

By writing $\Gamma, x: \tau_1$, we are considering a context $\Gamma$
where the variable $x$ has type $\tau_1$, ignoring what the type of
$x$ may have been in context $\Gamma$ alone. If $x$ could be assigned
a type in the context $\Gamma$ alone, it would refer to some homonymous variable that is irrelevant to the abstraction, since its scope is shadowed in the abstraction by the local variable $x$. Indeed, an $\alpha$-conversion would make $x$ disappear from $e$ altogether.

In other words: $\Gamma \vdash x: \tau_1$ may or may not be true, but
it is simply irrelevant to typing the abstraction.

Then, it is possible that $\Gamma \vdash e: \tau_2$. But that is only
possible if the type of $x$ is irrelevant, for example when $x$ does
not actually occurs in $e$, as for the abstarction $\lambda x.42$,
Then $e=42$ which is indeed typable. But in general, you cannot type $e$ without having a type for $x$ (for the variable $x$ of the abstraction).

In other words, you expect the type of $e$ to be in general related to the type of $x$, and it is their relation that the rule is intended to express.

What the rule says is that, if by adding to the context $\Gamma$ that the *new*
variable $x$ has type $\tau_1$, you can infer then that $e$ has type
$\tau_2$ in this new environment, then the abstraction $\lambda x. e$
has type $\tau_1 \rightarrow \tau_2$ in the original environment
$\Gamma$.

It says that the type of $e$ is dependent on the type $x$ may have.

Then, wherever the abstraction is applied to another expression $e'$, the type of the application is whathever the type of $e$ should be when the type of $x$ is that of $e'$.  But that is another typing rule.

Comment: “By writing Γ,x:τ 1, we are considering a context Γ where the variable x has type τ1, ignoring what the type of x may have been in context Γ alone.”: so in short there is a difference between Γ added x, and x is part of Γ.

Comment: @Hibou57 I am not sure what you mean by "Γ added x", and by "x is part of
Γ". All I am saying is that explicit type assigment to the variable x
will supersede any that may be (if any) already in Γ. This is actually
how shadowing of variables operates, regarding typing (shadowing is
also called scope hole in programming languages). At least I believe
that is what is intended in your document. I do not recall using the
word "shadowing" for that phenomenon.

Comment: I meant “temporarily or locally added”, you say shadowing, which is clearer. Don't mind, your answer was clear to me and will probably be for others.

Comment: It is customary to *not* allow repetition of variables in a context, so actually most books will tacitly assume there is no $x$ in $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer, what do you mean with “repetition”? I don't understand, as to me all variables are unique and have a unique biding (for FP only, not imperative).

Comment: You can't have the context $x : \mathtt{int}, y : \mathtt{bool}, x : \mathtt{int}$ because it repeats the variable $x$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The λ-expression being typed is what it is, and may have a bound variable x used within the scope of another. Do books also assume it never happens, or is there another way to deal with it. I am not sure everyone wants implicit α-conversion.

Comment: Look up "de Bruijn convention", it assumes that any bound variable that might clash with one in the outer scope is tacitly renamed. This of course is not how one would implement things, but theoreticians like to do it to sweep details of $\alpha$-conversion under the carper.

Comment: I had forgotten about "De Bruijn convention" (something in my far
past), a terminology that appears only 18 times over the internet. The
proper name to use seems to be "De Bruijn index". Still, considering
the level of the question asked, I do not think wise to bring this
kind of sophistication. Furthermore, there seems to be no mathematical
necessity here. The variable x does not have to appear several times
in Γ. The notation Γ,x:τmay simply mean a new context which is like Γ
except that it types x with τ, whether Γtyped x or not. It is quite
standard and mathematically sound.

Comment: Is $\Gamma(x) = \tau$ the same as $\Gamma,x : \tau$? If not, I may open another question for this one notation or update the actual question to add this one.

Comment: (answering myself to the above) Obviously not the same. Remains another one: is $x : \tau \in \Gamma$ the same as $\Gamma(x) = \tau$ ? I guess the former suggest a declared type while the latter suggest an implied/computed type, while I'm not sure…

Comment: Seems $\Gamma,x : \tau$ can also be written $\Gamma \cup \{x : \tau\}$ (more readable, at least to me).

Comment: @Hibou57 There are often many ways to look at definitions (or to avoid having
to look at them, as with De Bruijn index, in more advanced work on
these issues). My own inclination is to see Γ as a substitution, i.e. a
mapping from variables to types. So if you define Γ' as Γ,x:τ, then Γ'
is a mapping identical to Γ, except for the argument x for which it
gives the type τ. So you have Γ'(x)=τ, which is a property of Γ', not
a notation to define it. But you can say nothing of Γ(x), which may
even be undefined.

Comment: “you can say nothing of Γ(x)”: this one is important. Should always keep in mind, when seeing a function, it may be undefined (I too much tend to see functions as always defined or total, even where nothing states it).

Comment: @Hibou57 Then the notation x:τ∈Γ is a statement equivalent to Γ(x)=τ,
but it is not a definition of anything. And in the context of your
question, it is wrong as Γ may not even be defined for the variable
x. - - - Writing Γ∪{x:τ} is clearly wrong, as a homonymous bound
variable x may already be associated in Γ with another type, thus
causing ambiguity. The closest which would make sense would be to see
Γ as an ordered list of pairs, with new pairs on the right end, and
searched from right to left to find the type of a variable. This is
used when implementing contexts.